# Ionic/Laravel - Cors issue in Android real device

Tags: android, cors, ionic3, laravel-5.8

I have this error when calling API in my ionic Android app.
I deploy the app using:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

The error is:

```
 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.1.101:8888/......' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

If I run in browser I have same problem but I solve it using the Chrome extension "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *"

The server is Laravel 5.8: I already added Cors middleware.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the problem.
It was a problem on my Laravel server that I solve installing a plugin.
No problem in Ionic app code.